# Alternative to doodle

Tags: gratis, open-source, project-management, calendar

I have to find free times in my calendar and the calendars of people I work with. I know I can do that with [doodle](http://doodle.com) or [When Is Good](http://whenisgood.net/).

Since I want to protect the privacy of those people (usually you invite them by email address), I wonder whether there's an open-source solution to those mentioned above that I could install on my web server.

Requirements:

- web-based planning for the organizer
- scheduling down to 15 minute starting time and duration
- web-based answer by participants
- invitation by email address
- run on a typical Ubuntu Linux LAMP installation (PHP, mySQL)
- open-source / gratis

So far

- I know [Dudle](https://dudle.inf.tu-dresden.de/?lang=en) but it needs Ruby and I could not find installation instructions, so I hesitate using that.
- I found [Pleft](https://github.com/sander/pleft), but this is based on Python.

Comment: Maybe a bit overhead, but might [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) fit this? Runs on PHP, and has what you've described plus more.

Comment: @Izzy: did they remove the limitation that you can connect to one ownCloud only? I logged on at the demo system and could find a calendar but not a doodle-like feature. Is this feature available in a separate app?

Comment: I didn't try exactly that, so I don't know (otherwise I'd placed an answer showing it works) – but yes, you can "combine ownClouds" somehow. If I remember correctly, that was introduced somewhere with OC7 and improved with OC8 (the current version). Though whether it has a "Doodle-like component", I'm not sure. It was [requested in 2013](https://github.com/owncloud/apps/issues/712), and there seems to be [an app for that](https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/Polls?content=167919) meanwhile (OC7+). Looks like what you want :)

Comment: I just suggested ownCloud in, like, 5 other questions, but it seems a bit overkill for this usecase! But yes, the remote ownCloud thingy works.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking at Framadate: 
https://framacloud.org/fr/cultiver-son-jardin/framadate.html

( See also: https://framadate.org/ )

It is originally based on Studs, a software of the university of Strassbourg.
The development is currently done by the Framasoft association.
License: CeCILL-B.

Comment: @Thomas Weller: Framadate will maybe not meet all your requirements, but worth checking as it may help you.

Comment: I like the looks of this software. I can't seem to get it running though. Does anyone know if there's an english install manual for this? I can't find one and google translate doesn't go far enough. I think I am 99% of the way there, but I get apache / sql errors when I try to run the site/admin/install.php file.  

`[Thu Feb 01 18:19:17.181801 2018] [:error] [pid 2722] [client 135.23.53.119:50580] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'date_fin' in /var/www/framadat$`

Comment: @Frantumn: I didn't try installing it, buy using phpMyAdmin you could check how far Framadate could install, especially if the database and its tables were created. Why not add some  PHP `echo` function in the file where the error occurs to understand what's happening?

Comment: This looks like a great option for those of us not wanting self-hosted, but just wanting a private alternative to adware Doodle. Main downside: No timezone support, and it looks like it's not going to be added either.

Answer (score 0):

How about [wiggio](https://wiggio.com)? Although not Open Source, it is free, web-based, invitation by email, web-based answers by participants, you can manually set the time to 15 min instead of 30 min intervals, so I think it looks like it is doing what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wiggio does no longer exist.

Comment: Confirming that the website seems broken. I get a "Your connection is not private" error.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lukevella/Rallly - Rallly is a free collaborative scheduling service https://rallly.co

also with docker-compose

Comment: Please post a screenshot showing how it can be used in the scenario of this question. Also, please say for each requirement whether Rallly fulfills it or not.

Comment: Ways Rally does replace doodle: Elegant way to pick a date for a meeting. Limitations that don't come close to replacing Doodle: No support for times of day, just the date itself. No support for timezones.